# Solr - How do I match all user provided tokens, not just some?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm currently experimenting with Solr and attempting to get a query to only retrieve documents where all the provided tokens match.

For example, assume I have a field called *data* which when indexed uses a PatternTokenizer to split the incoming string on a delimiting character, e.g. '/'. For the input string "Foo/Bar/Baz" I would expect to get three tokens (if my understanding of the docs is correct!). Adding a few more documents I end up with:

Foo/Bar/Baz ==> Foo, Bar, Baz

Foo/Far/Faz ==> Foo, Far, Faz

Boo/Bar/Baz ==> Boo, Bar, Baz

When I come to query this field however, I get results I wasn't quite expecting. Using the query:

```
+data:Foo/Bar
```

I would expect this to match documents which contained *both* Foo and Bar, but instead it returns documents which contain at least Foo or Bar, scoring those with both terms higher. Other than altering the query such that it resembles:

```
+data:Foo +data:Bar
```

is there any way to change the behaviour such that instead of matching all 3 of my example documents, it matches only the one?

This experiment was done using the nightly builds of Solr 4.0.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so... but what's the problem with using `AND`s or `+`? It makes things more explicit...

Comment: OK, that's fine - I'll use the '+' syntax. This was more for an exercise in learning how the various parts of Lucene/Solr work, not something that absolutely had to be made to work! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the default operator to be AND in schema.xml which will make all queries an AND search.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator

You could also change it per-query by adding q.op=AND to the solr url.

http://solrhost/solr/select?q=solr+lucene&q.op=AND